# Unexpected word breaker results on Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT occurrence, display_term 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"ROBIX 156 DM"', 1033, null, 0)
```

does not return expected results (display_term):

```
robix
156
nn156
dm
```

but

```
robix
156 dm
nn156dm
```

What is 'DM', why its resulting in unexpected result from word breaker, and how could one avoid it ?

Answer (score 0):

What is likely happening here is that DM is being recognized as a currency (Deutsche Mark) which is causing the word breaker to associate with the leading numerical value. I tried replacing DM with USD and ended up getting the same results -

```
SELECT occurrence, display_term  
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"ROBIX 156 USD"', 1033, null, 0)

occurrence  display_term
1   robix
2   156 usd
2   nn156usd
```

I do not know of a work-around at this point, but will update the thread if and when I do find a solution.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to perform explicit queries such as your example?  I have the same problem when searching for AZM - if the indexed text is "AZM 30", the display_terms are "azm 30" and "nn30azm" - however, if the AZM is lowercased as in "azm 30", then the display_terms are "azm", "30", and "nn30".  
hopefully i can get around this as i don't want to load up an older word breaker or lowercase everything.

Answer (score 0):

The Parser is identifying currency you can confirm that using:

```
SELECT occurrence, display_term 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"ROBIX 156 euro"', 1033, null, 0)
```

```
occurrence  display_term
1           robix
2           156 euro
2           nn156eur
```

Comment: Can you edit that and format code or output as code (use the {} icon). It's not clear what's output and how that output is formatted.